# Remove all rows in cell array A that are in cell array B

Tags: matlab, difference, cell-array

I have a cell array `A` in `MATLAB` as follow

```
A = { 'U2', 'T13', 'A52';  
      'U2', 'T15', 'A52';  
      'U2', 'T18', 'A52';  
      'U2', 'T17', 'A995'; 
      'U4', 'T18', 'A53';  
      'U4', 'T13', 'A64';  
      'U4', 'T18', 'A64';
    }
```

I also have a cell array `B` as follow:

```
B = { 'U2', 'T13', 'A52';  
      'U2', 'T18', 'A52';   
      'U4', 'T13', 'A64';  
      'U4', 'T18', 'A64';
     }
```

How to generate cell array `C` is equal to `A` - `B`:

```
C = { 'U2', 'T15', 'A52';  
      'U2', 'T17', 'A995'; 
      'U4', 'T18', 'A53';  
    }
```

How to get `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner should serve your purposes:

```
C = A(sum(~ismember(A,B),2) > 0,:)
```

The output is:

```
C =
    3×3 cell array
    'U2'    'T15'    'A52' 
    'U2'    'T17'    'A995'
    'U4'    'T18'    'A53'
```

Basically, the row elements of `A` that are not found in `B` show a row-wise summation value greater than `0`. That reference value is then used to produce a logical indexing that catches the element not present in `B`.

There is a nice overload of the [ismember](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function that accepts `rows` as third input argument in order to perform row-wise matchings. This would really simplify this computation, but unfortunately it is not supported for cell array inputs.

**EDIT**

```
A = {
  'U2' 'T13' 'A52';  
  'U2' 'T15' 'A52';  
  'U2' 'T18' 'A52';  
  'U2' 'T17' 'A995'; 
  'U4' 'T18' 'A53';  
  'U4' 'T13' 'A64';  
  'U4' 'T18' 'A64'
};

B = {
  'U2' 'T13' 'A52';  
  'U2' 'T18' 'A52';   
  'U4' 'T13' 'A64';  
  'U4' 'T18' 'A64'
};

A_len = size(A,1);
A_keys = cell(A_len,1);

for i = 1:A_len
    A_keys{i} = horzcat(A{i,:});
end

B_len = size(B,1);
B_keys = cell(B_len,1);

for i = 1:B_len
    B_keys{i} = horzcat(B{i,:});
end

C = A(~ismember(A_keys,B_keys),:);
```

Comment: thanks. I test the code in more large data set. it seems that the results is not what I expected. My goal is try to treat each `rows` as a unit element, and remove the `rows` in `B`.

Comment: This seems kinda strange. Do you have duplicate rows?

Comment: not duplicate rows. I try to split the `A` into two disjoint set `B` and `C`. I have `B` and try to remove `B`'s elemtents in `A` to generate `C`.

Comment: I can't see the reason why the above code should fail though. Anyway, let's try with something stronger...

Comment: The dataset is really huge and I cannot test it right now. Did the code I added to my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no repeated rows,

```
C = setdiff(A,B,'rows');
```

should do what you want. See the [documentation for `setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

Comment: setdiff has the same problem of ismember: the 'rows' option does not support cell arrays, unless one of the inputs is either a categorical array or a datetime array.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo: I wasn't aware of that limitation. Thanks!